# ES6 Class Method Scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm playing around with some ES6 features and I'm trying to convert some of my old code's class structure to an ES6 class equivalent.

```
var App = function() {

    /**
     * Public method calling a private method.
     */
    this.init = function() {
        events();
    };

    /**
     * Private method.
     */
    var handleClickEvent = function() {
        console.log('Click handled');
    };

    /**
     * Private method with event calling private
     * method in this class.
     */
    var events = function() {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClickEvent);
    };

};

(new App).init();
```

Is this the correct approach by making the methods `static` or is there a `private` equivalent, also can static methods be called form outside the class like `App.events()`?

```
class App {

    constructor() {
        App.events();
    }

    static handleClickEvent() {
        console.log('Click handled');
    }

    static events() {
        document.addEventListener('click', App.handleClickEvent);
    }

}

new App();
```